# Qt QCombobox change Scroll Arrows

Tags: c++, css, qt

Hello i have a problem with the ComboBox in QT.
I have searched for a while now but i could not find any information.

I have to build a Combobox to select some Data 
http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160606/2ekorosf.png

[image]

The up and down arrows at the end of the list are way too narrow.
I want them bigger.
Is there a way to change this?

With a normal scrollbar everthing works fine with my css-file
for example:

```
QScrollBar:vertikal {with: 50px;}
```

But I can not figure out how to change the small arrows in the picture.

Answer (score 2):

this does not work.
I noticed that my problem is not wit the CamboBox. This Programm uses

QComboBox QAbstractItemView

it seems that i need to change the autoScrollMargin(or setAutoScrollMargin) in some way
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#autoScrollMargin-prop
but i could not figure out hot to do it in a CSS file,
sry i am pretty new in Qt.^^

--

i figured something out, if i use

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
margin-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

i got something like this 
[QComboBox QAbstractItemView margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6DIb.png)

this nearly what i was hoping for. 
I will keep you up to date.^^

Answer (score 0):

You can customize QComboBox' arrows using:

```
QComboBox::up-arrow {
    width: Npx;
    height: Npx;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow { 
    width: Npx;
    height: Npx;
}

// Where "N" is the width and height you want to set.
```

Take a look at this link if you want to see how to customize QComboBox: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html